# SAML bearer assertion flow for retrieving an OAuth token

Tags: oauth, saml

I am using SAML assertion to retrieve an OAuth token and I am using a custom apex class to generate the SAML assertion. My IDP is set to send User's FederationIdentitfier in Subject (SAML Response Pic), but in my Apex code where I am posting this SAML response to token end point, if I modify the SUBJECT to "4499", I am getting some timeout error.

Should the SUBJECT be User's 'username' only?

[image: SAML Response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the SUBJECT be User's 'username' only?

**Yes**, based on the documentation for [OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5), this needs to be username (emphasis mine):

> The `Subject` `NameID` **must be the username** of the desired Salesforce user.

Comment: Hey Jayant, thanks for answering my question. Actually I have 2 service provider orgs, SP1 and SP2 and I have obtained my SAML response from IDP into SP1. Now, in order to connect SP1 and SP2 I am using the oauth SAML response from SP1 and posting it to oAuth token end point (which is a connected app in SP2). Now, if I have to put user's username is the Subject (in SP1), then which user would that be SP1 user or SP2 user? because these 2 username's are different only the federationId is common.

Comment: @ShruthiKy Comments are meant for follow ups on the question. But in this case, you have a completely different question in your comments. You should open this as a new question for someone to be able to help you on that specific issue. The answer here was [specific to your original question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) based on the format of SFSE.